# How to change User Agent?

Tags: swift, xcode

Im making an app for Mac and the app is basically a `WebView` inside the `viewController` which can be accessed from the menu bar.

Its working fine, the webpages load from the menu bar. But the `WebView` loads the full page as if it was opened from `Safari`. How do I change this so that it opens the webpage as for example an iPhone?

Comment: If you're using (or can use) a `NSMutableRequest`, it has a method called `- addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001903-SW36):

WebView has a property named `customUserAgent`. Just set it to what you want.

```
var customUserAgent: String!
```

If you want to manipulate the application name inside that string use the `applicationNameForUserAgent` property:

```
var applicationNameForUserAgent: String!
```

To pretend coming from Mobile Safari on iOS 9.3,

```
yourWebViewInstance.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13E188a Safari/601.1"
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent": "Custom-Agent"])
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! Apple.com shows now up in mobile version but not google.com or twitter.com. Why is that?

Comment: hmmm, did you try http://google.com, http://www.google.com, google.com, www.google.comm??????

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xakzo06576ofojh/Skjermbilde%202016-09-01%20kl.%2015.43.01.png?dl=0