# How to request desktop site in Swift programmatically (without UIWebView)?

Tags: html, ios, request, thumbnails, user-agent

Desktop site's HTML code has a link of "apple-touch-icon" thumbnail image in header, whereas mobile's one hasn't.
I just need to fetch this html and parse.

So, how to request desktop site (maybe via URLRequest, URLSession or something else)?

p.s.
I found, that I have to change `User-Agent` string value, but again, I didn't find, how to do this in Swift.

Comment: without webview?why without webview?you only need html for the link?

Comment: yeah. I need stored in the HTML code link to the site's thumbnail image. That's all. I'll not display the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on server logic, but in most cases it's enough to set up userAgent Header in you request:

```
let url = URL(string:"https://google.com")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1 Safari/605.1.12"
request.addValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
 // Process reponse
}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 2):

A WKWebView should solve your problem - you can define it in your code. Do this:

```
var webView : WKWebView!
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
    self.webView!.uiDelegate = self
    webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"
    //load URL here
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url as URL))
    self.view.addSubview(webView)


}
```

Comment: For information on changing the user-agent in swift please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271245/how-to-change-user-agent