# Request desktop site WKWebview not working in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, user-agent

I tried almost everything one stackoverflow and other site to request desktop version of site in WKWebview, but none of solution is working for me.

my tried links as below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38228810/3145189

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38228810/3145189

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49646773/3145189

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48155481/3145189

i tried on above threads to get answers by commenting on answers, but got no reply so here i go with my question, i hope you won't mark it duplicate

Here is my one of implementation out of many i tried

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var webview: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webview = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
        self.webview.uiDelegate = self


        let url = URL(string: "https://quora.com/")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"
        request.addValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        webview.load(request)

        //webview.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"
        self.view.addSubview(webview)

    }
}

extension ViewController: WKUIDelegate {
}
```

I would request, please test you answer or suggestion before posting answer, as i have tried so many other things.

**Edit-**

Above sample code is working fine, problem is changing user-agent don't reflect immediately, on reinstallation user-agent change does reflect, so my question is how to toggle request desktop site by using button.

Comment: Setting the property customUserAgent properly should be enough

Comment: i tried but didn't worked - webview.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"

Comment: The Quora website will be a responsive website which will set styles based on screen width, not just user agent. you may need to adjust the size/zoom level on the webview, it might help

Comment: Quora website is working fine on safari app, UIWebView when request for desktop site, as well as i tried with other sites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my tested code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var webview: WKWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        createWebView()
        if let url = URL(string: "https://quora.com") {
            load(url: url)
        }
    }

    private func createWebView() {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let webview = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
        webview.uiDelegate = self
        webview.navigationDelegate = self
        self.webview = webview
        self.view.addSubview(webview)
    }

    private func load(url: URL) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"
        request.addValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        webview?.load(request)
    }
}

extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("\(#function)")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("\(#function): \(error)")
    }
}

extension ViewController: WKUIDelegate {

}
```

And the resulting page:
[image: iPhone 7Plus screenshot of WKWebview with Quora.com site]

Cheers!

Comment: thanks it's working fine, but now i figured out mine sample code in question is also working fine :) , so problem is of caching changing user agent don't reflect on re-run, once i re-install app it's work fine, could you please suggest what should i do to reflect user-agent change immediately ?

Comment: request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData